# How to filter Facebook post comments by time range

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Is there anyway to filter comments between a time range?

It looks like this was removed in a previous bug update, but I cannot be sure: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/420363721670492/

Basically, I want to grab all comments for a post (which I am now doing), but then I want to filter those comments between a date range. Any way to do this? It seems like *since* and *until* no longer works when testing in the api explorer.

Comment: can you post a sample API call? i am not having that issue

Comment: Just testing in the api explorer, I'm getting the comments for a post, then trying to tack on time_range={"since":"2018​-01-20","until":"2018-02-21"} but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: dont put since and until as properties to "time_range". do this: since="2018-01-20" instead of time_range={"since":"2018​-01-20"}

Comment: still doesn't work, for reference, I have something like this:

GET/V2.12/XXXX_XXXX?fields=comments which returns all comments back to me on a particular post.

Then I add &since="2018-01-20"

which returns:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Parameter since: Must be a unixtime or a date/time representation parseable by strtotime()",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "CDrVgKr6PDu"
  }
}


So instead I convert to unix timestamp

GET/V2.12/XXXX_XXXX?fields=comments&since="1516406400"

but it returns the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't do "fields=comments", do "GET/V2.12/XXXX_XXXX/comments "

Answer (score 0):

When using the unix timestamp, there should be no quotes, it is not a time format string.
Change your call to:
GET/V2.12/XXXX_XXXX?fields=comments&since=1516406400